# Не работают модели Django из Docker

Tags: python, django, docker

Внутри докера получаю ошибку

```
from . import views
  File "/code/apps/graph/views.py", line 15, in <module>
    from models import Session
  File "/code/apps/graph/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Article(models.Model):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 111, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class models.Article doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in 
an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    """
    Описание статьи для хранения ее в базе данных SQLite
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.parsing',
    'apps.graph',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Вы не забыли сделать миграции?

Comment: Попробуйте прописать полный путь к классу приложения, то есть `apps.parsing` и `apps.graph` заменить на `apps.parsing.apps.ParsingConfig` и `apps.graph.apps.GraphConfig` соответственно.

Comment: Ого,как говориться,было интересно,ничего не понял. Но оно заработало. Спасибо. Ох уж эти пути

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указывайте полный путь к классу приложения.

***Пример:***

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.parsing.apps.ParsingConfig',
    'apps.graph.apps.GraphConfig',
]
```

Именно классы отвечают за то, как `Django` воспринимает Ваше приложение.

***apps/parsing/apps.py:***

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ParsingConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'parsing'
```